# Помогите сократить код функции. Django

Tags: python, django

Не могу додуматься как можно сократить и привести к хорошему виду эту функцию:

```
@login_required(login_url='login_page')
def todo_create(request):
    quantity_todos = Profile.objects.all().values("quantity_todos")
    todos = Todo.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    profile = request.user.profile
    form = TodoCreateForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TodoCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if request.user.profile.quantity_todos < 10 or request.user.profile.premium_status == True:
                todo = form.save(commit = False)
                todo.user=request.user
                todo.save()
                profile.quantity_todos += 1
                profile.save()
                return redirect('todo_list')
            elif request.user.profile.quantity_todos >= 10 and request.user.profile.premium_status == False:
                return redirect("profile_change_status_page")
    context = {'form':form, 'todos':todos, 'categories':categories}
    return render(request, 'todolist/todo_create.html', context)
```

Кто знает, как ее можно сократить, сократите пожалуйста или подскажите как правильно.

Comment: Вопрос - зачем тут что-то сокращать? Единственное, что тут можно улучшить, насколько я вижу, это заменить `elif request.user.profile.quantity_todos >= 10 and request.user.profile.premium_status == False:` просто на `else:`, потому что условие противоположно условию в if.

Comment: Окей, спасибо))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
todo.user=request.user
```

Можно передавать в форму в `__init__()` и в `save` формы перед сохранением объекта класть в поле

```
                profile.quantity_todos += 1
                profile.save()
```

Аналогично, но только в `save` формы

```
request.user.profile.quantity_todos < 10 or request.user.profile.premium_status == True
```

Можно вынести в метод модели `Profile`, например `can_add_todo`. Будет выглядеть так

```
def can_add_todo(self):
    return self.quantity_todos < 10 or self.premium_status
```

Все эти изменения не обязательны, стоит подумать о них только если код дублируется в разных местах

---

Что касается изменений - в дополнение к комментарию @insolor

```
request.user.profile.quantity_todos < 10 or request.user.profile.premium_status == True
```

В условии `== True` лишний, так как если `request.user.profile.premium_status` равен `True` то и вернет `True` и нет смысла сравнивать `True` с `True`. Можно заменить на

```
request.user.profile.quantity_todos < 10 or request.user.profile.premium_status
```

А еще вы создали переменную `profile` и не используете.
Можно заменить то же условие на

```
profile.quantity_todos < 10 or profile.premium_status
```

при условии, что не вынесли блок

```
                profile.quantity_todos += 1
                profile.save()
```

в `save`. В противном случае, стоит проверить, что все отрабатывает правильно, если нет - всегда можно сделать `profile.refresh_from_db()`

Comment: Спасибо большое.. С True как раз надо разобраться